# Bulk Change Properties of an Array

Tags: arrays, properties

I've been working with Flash for a few days now for fun as a seventeen-year-old, and I've been trying to streamline my code. Is there any way to change ALL the objects in an array to match a property with a single code?

Here's what I'm currently using.

```
var caseArray:Array = new Array(5); caseArray = [CaseBlack50, CaseWhite50, CaseRed50, CaseBlack75, CaseWhite75];
var A01:Number = 0;

while (A01 < 5){caseArray[A01].x = -500; A01++}
```

I could also do it like this:

```
caseArray[0].x = -500;
caseArray[1].x = -500;
caseArray[2].x = -500;
caseArray[3].x = -500;
caseArray[4].x = -500;
```

Is there any way I could turn it into something like this?

```
caseArray[ALL].x = -500; //or
caseArray[0,1,2,3,4].x = -500 //or
caseArray.x = -500
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, doing the loop is the best way of doing this.

I personally prefer to use a `for` loop, but that's just a taste.